# DOM element reappearing after empty() called

Tags: ajax, jquery, click

I have a button which when clicked the first time it will load another html page.
When it is clicked the second time it will empty a div of the loaded page.

However, for some reason the loaded content keeps reappearing after the second click....

CSS:

```
#boatdiv {
    width: 100%;    
}

.clicked {}
```

HTML

```
<button id="load"></button>
<div id="boatdiv"></div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajaxSetup ({  
        cache: false  
    }); 
    var loadURL = "AjaxLoad_injection.html";
    $("#load").on("click", function() {
        if(!($(this).hasClass("clicked"))){ //checks if button has NOT been clicked
        $("#boatdiv").html("<p>loading...</p>").load(loadURL);  
        }
        else {
        $("#boatdiv").empty();
        }
        $("#boatdiv").toggleClass("clicked");
        }
    );


}); // end ready
```

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You test `$(#load)` but toggle `$("boatdiv")`.

Try :

```
$("#load").on("click", function() {
    if(!($(this).hasClass("clicked"))){ //checks if button has NOT been clicked
        $("#boatdiv").html("<p>loading...</p>").load(loadURL);  
    }
    else {
        $("#boatdiv").empty();
    }
    $(this).toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You are toggling class on wrong element. You want it to toggle on the element being clicked. Same as code I gave you in last post.

Simple to walk through it, you are testing `this`... so need to toglle the class on `this`

Use

```
$(this).togglClass('clicked')
```

Comment: Ah, yeah.... I noticed that I should have just copied your code exactly. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Remember that ajax calls are asynchronous. You may be clicking the button a second time before the ajax call has returned.

You could disable the button during the ajax call, like this:

```
$('#load').on('click', function() {
    if (!$(this).hasClass("clicked")) {
        $('#load').attr('disabled', true);
        $("#boatdiv").html("<p>loading...</p>").load(loadURL, function() {
            $('#load').attr('disabled', false);
        });  
    } else {
        $('#boatdiv').empty();
    }
    //$('#boatdiv').toggleClass("clicked");
    $('#load').toggleClass("clicked");
});
```

The button is disabled before the ajax call. A callback function is passed as a second parameter to the "load()" function. It will be called when the ajax call returns. It will re-enable the button.

EDIT: I missed that the wrong element was getting the class toggled, but I still think you want to disable the button during the ajax call or things can get messed up.

Comment: Yeah, that's helpful. Thanks for this!